# Dirichlet distribution when parameters $\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading a paper where they model a $\overrightarrow{\pi}$ random vector which is Dirichlet distributed in this way:
$$
\overrightarrow{\pi}|\alpha\overrightarrow{w}\sim Dir(\alpha w_{1}+1, ...,\alpha w_{N}+1)
$$
where $$|\overrightarrow{w}|=|\overrightarrow{\pi}|=N$$
so $\overrightarrow{\pi}$ has the following density function:
$$
P(\overrightarrow{\pi}|\alpha \overrightarrow{w})=\frac{\Gamma (\alpha \eta+N)}{\prod_i \Gamma(\alpha w_i+1)}\prod_i (\pi_{i})^{\alpha w_i}
$$
where 
$$
\eta=\sum_i w_i
$$
The paper claims that $\pi_i\rightarrow\frac{w_i}{\eta} $ when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$, that is not obvious to me why it is true.I would appreciate if someone could provide me the reason behind that, or reference  some related materials to study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wikpedia page for the [Dirichlet Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) we see that if the random vector $X$ is distributed as 
$$X \sim Dir(\beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n)$$
then the mean of $X_i$ is given by
$$E[X_i] = \frac{\beta_i - 1}{B - n} $$
where $B = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i$ and has variance
$$Var[X_i] = \frac{\beta_i(B - \beta_i)}{B^2(B+1)}$$

In your problem $X = \pi$, $\beta_i = \alpha w_i + 1$ so we have
$$E[\pi_i] = \frac{\alpha w_i}{\alpha \eta} = \frac{w_i}{\eta}$$
and 
$$Var[\pi_i] = \frac{(\alpha w_i + 1)(W - (\alpha w_i + 1))}{W^2(W+1)}$$
where $W = \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha w_i + 1)$

First observe that
$$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} Var[\pi_i] = 0$$
since $W \sim \alpha$ as $\alpha \to \infty$, so the numerator is second order in $\alpha$ and the denominator is third order in $\alpha$.

This means that each $\pi_i$ converges to its mean:
$$E[\pi_i] = \frac{w_i}{\eta}$$

Comment: Great answer.thanks